# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new with spring MVC, I am trying to create Contact Manager application using MVC with spring framework and annotation. at run time I am getting `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed` exception.I have searched lot on this but I am confuse what is the exact reason for this exception.

Solutions Which I found:

1. Missing dependency- I have checked all the dependency
2. different version- It is generated by Spring framework itself, so I guess its correct
3. base-package scan- I have provided the base-package to scan.

Please help me in this.

1. Can any body explain me why do we get this exception ?.
2. What is wrong with my code that I am getting this exception ?.

Please help me with this I am stuck since last 3 days.

**StackTrace**

```
13:15:41,769 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.varun.contact.dao.ContactDao com.varun.contact.controller.HomeController.contactDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.varun.contact.dao.ContactDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecut
13:15:41,770 INFO  [STDOUT] or$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.varun</groupId>
    <artifactId>contact</artifactId>
    <name>Contact</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jdbc template -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String telephone;

    // Default Constructor........
    public Contact()
    {
    }
    // Parameterized Constructor
    public Contact(String name, String email, String address,
            String telephone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    //Getters and setters I have just removed here to save the space.
```

**ContactDao** **Interface**

```
package com.varun.contact.dao;
import java.util.List; 
import com.varun.contact.model.Contact;

public interface ContactDao {
    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact);
    public void delete(int contactId);
    public Contact get(int contactId);
    public List<Contact> list();

}
```

**ContactDAOImpl**

```
package com.varun.contact.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.varun.contact.model.Contact;


import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
//import com.varun.contact.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     public ContactDAOImpl(javax.activation.DataSource dataSource) {
            jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate((DataSource) dataSource);
        }


    //Insert or update a new contact: 
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
        if(contact.getId()>0){
            //Update
            String sql="UPDATE CONTACT SET name=?,email=?,address=?,"
            +"telephone=? where contact_id=?";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql,contact.getName(),contact.getEmail(),contact.getAddress(),
                    contact.getTelephone(),contact.getId());
        }
        else{
            // Insert
            String sql="INSERT INTO CONTACT(name,email,address,telephone)"
                    +"VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql,contact.getName(),contact.getEmail(),contact.getAddress(),
                    contact.getTelephone());
        }

    }   
    //Delete a contact:
    @Override
    public void delete(int contactId) {
    String sql="DELETE FROM CONTACT where contact_id=?";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql,contactId);         
    }

    //Get a particular contact:
    @Override
    public Contact get(int contactId) {

        String sql="SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE contact_id="+contactId;
         return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Contact>() {

                @Override
                public Contact extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                        DataAccessException {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        contact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
                        contact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                        contact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                        contact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                        contact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));
                        return contact;
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            });
    }

    //List all contact:
    @Override
    public List<Contact> list() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact";
        List<Contact> listContact = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Contact>() {

            @Override
            public Contact mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Contact aContact = new Contact();

                aContact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
                aContact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                aContact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                aContact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                aContact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));
                return aContact;
            }

        });
        return listContact;
    }
}
```

**MvcConfiguration**

```
package com.varun.contact.config;

//I have removed all import to save space

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.varun.contact")
@EnableWebMvc

public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;        
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

     @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl");
            dataSource.setUsername("system");
            dataSource.setPassword("admin");

            return (DataSource) dataSource;
        }

     @Bean
        public ContactDao getContactDao() {
            return new ContactDAOImpl(getDataSource());
        }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
package com.varun.contact.controller;

  // I have removed all import
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);


    @Autowired
    private ContactDao contactDao;


    //Handler method for listing all contacts (also served as home page):
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
        java.util.List<Contact> listContact = contactDao.list();
        model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
        model.setViewName("home");

        return model;
}
    //Handler method for displaying new contact form:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        model.addObject("contact", newContact);
        model.setViewName("ContactForm");
        return model;
    }

    //Handler method for inserting/updating a contact:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) 
    {
    contactDao.saveOrUpdate(contact);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    //Handler method for retrieving details of a particular contact for editing:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Contact contact = contactDao.get(contactId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
        model.addObject("contact", contact);

        return model;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to add `@Component` on your `ContactDAOImpl` class (or `@Repository`).

Comment: Did not work I am getting same error.

Comment: The error says that none of the application contextes (neither root nor MVC) contains a bean for `ContactDAOImpl`. You should use a higher log level to know exactly what beans are created in what ApplicationContest

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 @Repository("ContactDao")
    public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDao
    ....
```

I don't think the bean declaration is needed in this case.

Comment: Still i am  getting the same error after using  @Repository("ContactDao")

Comment: Yes I guess in this case the ("ContactDao") is not helping, but I saw that doing just @Respository does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Either do as below:

```
@Repository
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDao {
```

or as below:

```
@Component
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDao {
```

Comment: This Repository
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDao {   -worked  error is gone but Application is not running bro, can you please helm me this

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `ContactDaoImpl` is getting created by Spring? Because I believe if there is an error/exception in the constructor (for example when you create your data source) the bean wont be created properly. Have you tried putting a `try`/`catch` into the constructor to check if it actually gets called?